# Creating a rule to organize sent folder for emails "sent as" a distribution group

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange

I am using Outlook/Exchange Online. I have a distribution group that I will be sending emails "as."

I want to separate my "sent folder" between my actual email and emails that were "sent as."

I understand that I can set a rule for:

1) Apply rule on messages I send
2) "Through the specified account"

However, I only have the option of my mailbox. I think "through the specified account" only allows you to choose mailboxes that you've added on Outlook, but not distribution groups.

Is there anyway to set up a rule for emails "sent as" a distribution group? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No direct rules could be applied to emails ‘sent as’ the distribution group.

You can assign a category to this kind of emails and create following rule:

[image]

Another workaround is to use Search folder to show these emails.

1. Click Folder > New Search Folder.
2. Type a name for this folder.
3. Click Criteria… and click Advanced tab.
4. Set following condition:

[image]

5. Then all your emails send as the DL will be show in this search folder.

[image]